# How can I make a menu similar to NFL.com's using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make a dropdown menu similar to [NFL.com's](http://nfl.com/) using jQuery? I really like the way it stays hidden, while still providing all the convince of a regular menu.

Answer (score 2):

NFL.com uses [Script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/), which was written by [Thomas Fuchs](http://scripty2.com)

See the [Script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/) site for lots of examples and demo code

The Effect.SlideDown and Effect.SlideUp should get you what you need for this type of menu.

Comment: Accurate information, but it isn't really an answer to this question. Unless you are expecting that he read the demo, script.acuo.us source, **and** the prototype source to see how to do it in plain javascript, and then translate it to jQuery.

Comment: @TM pointing out that the example in question uses a different framework, and suggesting it might be easier to just use that one instead of reinventing the wheel, is a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar can be achieved with jQuery using their [Slide effect](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide).  Essentially, each of those submenus will be contained in their own div, each positioned such that when fully visible you get the submenu under the main nav.  Then, simply start off with all of those subnav divs hidden, and apply the slide effect to show/hide them during mouseover/mouseout events.